# Android how organise coroutines in elegant way?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

What is the best way to organize coroutines for application in elegant way? I understand, the question seems odd. Let me show the example of *Executors*

Create an object
**AppExecutors.kt**

```java
object AppExecutors {

    private val main: Executor = MainThreadExecutor()
    private val util: Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)

    fun main(f: () -> Unit) {
        main.execute(f)
    }

    fun util(f: () -> Unit) {
        util.execute(f)
    }

    class MainThreadExecutor : Executor {
        private val mainThreadHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        override fun execute(command: Runnable?) {
            mainThreadHandler.post(command)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we can use this. Simple, minimal code, etc

```
val exe = AppExecutors
exe.util {
    val first = calculateFirst()
    val second = calculateSecond()
    val str = ("first = $first | second = $second")
    exe.main {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Executors $str", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Now, i'v tried to use this approach on coroutines
**AppCoRoutines.kt**

```
object AppCoRoutines{
    private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main
    private val ioContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO
    private val networkContext: CoroutineContext = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).asCoroutineDispatcher()
    private val singleContext: CoroutineContext = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()

    val ui: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(uiContext)
    val io: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(ioContext)
    val net: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(networkContext)
    val single: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(singleContext)
}
```

Now, use this:

```
val coRout = AppCoRoutines
coRout.ui.launch {
    val str: String = withContext(coRout.net.coroutineContext){
        val first = async { calculateFirst() }
        val second = async { calculateSecond() }
        ("first = $first | second = $second")
    }
    Toast.makeText(activity, "CoRoutine $str", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

No so elegant at all. Maybe someone could suggest more simple way? I'm not so good in this right now, so i'm using coroutines for just simple taks.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you creating your own executors? Coroutines offer this out of the box.

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val str: String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val first = async { calculateFirst() }
            val second = async { calculateSecond() }
            ("first = $first | second = $second")
        }
        Toast.makeText(activity, "CoRoutine $str", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

Comment: Hello! Thanks for reply!
The question is not about why am i doing this, but about how i can do this in a simple way, as i show with Executors example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `CoroutineScope` on the call-site (where ever you want to use your coroutines, e.g. `coRout.ui.launch` in the current implementation) of your coroutines. That way, you don't have to write and repeat `coRout.ui.launch` everywhere and also, you can avoid memory leaks in the current code (because your coroutines can be alive whilst your calling object wants to be destroyed)

For example, If you are inside a class, you can make your class extend `CoroutineScope` like below:

```
class SomeClass: CoroutineScope {
    val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + coRout.net.coroutineContext
}
```

Inside this class, you can use `launch` and `withContext` to easily handle your coroutines. You can also `cancel()` the `job` object when you know your class is being destroyed (like `onDestory` for android activities), so that all the coroutines for this class get cancelled.